# Initialize components in for loop from array data

Tags: vue.js

Trying initialize custom elements (3 buttons) in for loop but first element missing text.

LeftMenu.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="left-menu">  
      <MenuButton v-for="mytext in buttonList" v-bind:key="mytext" v-bind:mytext="mytext"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import MenuButton from './components/MenuButton.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'left-menu',
        components: {
            MenuButton
        },
        computed: {
            buttonList() {
                return ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"];
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    #left-menu {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
</style>
```

MenuButton.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="left-menu-button">
      {{mytext}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'left-menu-button',
        props: {
            mytext: String
        }           
    }
</script>

<style>
    #left-menu-button {
        width: 180px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import LeftMenu from './LeftMenu.vue'
import MenuButton from './components/MenuButton.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(LeftMenu)
}).$mount('#left-menu')

new Vue({
  render: h => h(MenuButton)
}).$mount('#left-menu-button');
```

I am new to vue and still trying to figure out how all part are connected and working together. It just seems very strange that I got 3 buttons but only last two of them have text and first one does not...may be someone can point me to my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've assigned an id of `left-menu-button` to each of your buttons. You've then told Vue to mount something into that id. The first element (i.e. first button) with that id will be treated as the mounting element, which blows away the text.

You should remove the ids from all elements within your templates. The only id should be the one within your HTML file. For styling purposes use classes instead of ids. Then create a single Vue instance (just one call to `new Vue`, not two) targeting the id of the element inside your HTML file.

It is possible to create multiple Vue instance directly using `new Vue` but that is rarely necessary. To do that you would need to have multiple target elements within your HTML file.

Comment: I knew that there was some small mistake! Thank you.